# posie-python and chef - pip install for python 2.7 and 3.6

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I have to support python2.7 and 3.6 on ubuntu 16.04

If I have both installed how do I tell chef using posie-python to install for both?  For example I want the below to be installed for python 2.7 and 3.6

```
 python_package "boto"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two resources:

```
python_package "boto" do
  python "2"
end

python_package "boto" do
  python "3"
end
```